# Help with Facebook Site URL / Site Domain (using Domain Forwarding)

Tags: architecture, facebook

I've posted this on Facebook developers forum, but things seem to move slowly over there and support is scarce so I'm trying stackoverflow:

I have a website using FB login button. My architecture is kind of simple:

I have a domain (let's call it example.com) on whois.com. My application is running in an EC2 instance inside Amazon with an elastic IP (let's call it 1.2.3.4). I configured domain forwarding on whois.com, so all requests to example.com* are forwarded to 1.2.3.4*. Everything works fine except that I cannot configure Site URL and Site Domain correctly. I get "API Error Code: 191" with every configuration I've tried...

It works if I use the EC2 public DNS address, but I obviously don't want to use that...

Anyone know what should be the correct Site URL and Site Domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Site domain has to match the domain that appears in the address bar of the user's browser when they are interacting the Facebook-related parts of your site.

Comment: I've tried. The address the user sees in the address bar is: `http://www.example.com/example/` so I've tried `Site URL: http://www.example.com/example/` and `Site Domain: example.com` with no success... any other suggestion? Is Domain Forwarding a problem for Facebook?

Comment: this error message means that the 'redirect' url you are passing in to facebook (the url they should have the user's browser navigate to after they log in) does not match the domain name you provided.  double check that all of your code for interacting with facebook specifies uses example.com as the domain.  if you think you are doing this but it still doesn't work, use a tool like fiddler2 or firebug to monitor all of the traffic you are sending to facebook and examine those querystrings and request bodies to double check.

Comment: In my case i'm now only setting an application and my base url will be something like http://sub.example.com/ and i tried to set this as app site url and that showing an error 'site url not a valid url' and even i tried to set the app domain as 'example.com' and even example and that also shows an error as 'not a valid domain' .. I dont know how to set now..?